# java programming homework 2015

Tags: java, arrays

i am having some issues with this question for my homework and was wondering if anyone has any ideas or insights to the answer really struggling ,,,,

You are to amend the program you created last week, this time however the program will ask you to
type the names that need to be stored. Once this is complete the program will display the names in
alphabetical order and display the number of characters for each name and the number of vowels
each name has.

Comment: Hi James, I suggest you show us the code you've at least attempted, also read this for asking questions in the future; http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: At the **very** least show us the program you created last week!

Comment: Sometimes, I believe such questions are auto-posted by a bot to keep the site busy.

Comment: Seriously this has to be best question of all time.

Comment: I wasn't around to see the program you created last week.  You should definitely  edit that into your question.

Comment: Hi James. This is an very easy task but I can understant this is difficult for you. Just split your task into each module and google it. You can complete your task in just 5-10 mins. Keep in mind, just copy pasting is useless, first try to understand how it works

Comment: Please don't copy-paste your teacher message to here directly. Spend little time for formatting homework before ask.

Comment: Did you even do last week's homework?

Answer (score 4):

Since this is *homework*, I'll give you a hint.  If you've studied the Java Collections, you can stored the names in alphabetical order.  If you've not got to collections yet, the you simply save them off as Strings as they come in.

When it's time to display them in alphabetical order you could:
- sort them before you display them
- or brute force it.  Loop thru your storage of names and display all the A's.  Then loop thru picking up the B's.

As for counting vowels, look at the Java documentation for the methods that are on the String class.  Hint - look for methods that return an "int".

Comment: String[] StudentNames = new String [8];
StudentNames[0]="Joel";
StudentNames[1]="Amy";
StudentNames[2]="Robert";
StudentNames[3]="Conor";
StudentNames[4]="Mark";
StudentNames[5]="Stewart";
StudentNames[6]="Jack";
StudentNames[7]="James";
for(int x=0; x<8; x++)
{
System.out.println(StudentNames[x]);
}

Comment: that is my code from the previous week which works and is simple enough but now I am having difficulties with my new work